# Test an object for NOT being a type

Tags: c#, syntax, object, testing

I know how to test an object to see if it is of a type, using the IS keyword e.g.

```
if (foo is bar)
{
  //do something here
}
```

but how do you test for it not being "bar"?, I can't seem to find a keyword that works with IS to test for a negative result.

BTW  - I have a horrible feeling this is soooo obvious, so apologies in advance...

Comment: It's a good question. It's not obvious if you've tried but can't figure it out. That said, you may want to look at some C# syntax tutorials where they spell all this stuff out, and stuff that you haven't even asked yourself yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if (!(foo is bar)) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [as operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(VS.71).aspx).

> The as operator is used to perform
>   conversions between compatible types.

```
bar aBar = foo as bar; // aBar is null if foo is not bar
```

Comment: Is this 'cryptic and weird' or taking advantage of language features?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific keyword

```
if (!(foo is bar)) ...
if (foo.GetType() != bar.GetType()) .. // foo & bar should be on the same level of type hierarchy
```

Answer (score 1):

You should clarify whether you want to test that an object is *exactly* a certain type or *assignable* from a certain type. For example:

```
public class Foo : Bar {}
```

And suppose you have:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

If you want to know whether foo is not Bar(), then you would do this:

```
if(!(foo.GetType() == tyepof(Bar))) {...}
```

But if you want to make sure that foo does not derive from Bar, then an easy check is to use the as keyword.

```
Bar bar = foo as Bar;
if(bar == null) {/* foo is not a bar */}
```

Comment: I love the foo as bar bit, because you will no doubt want to DO something with foo if it is a Bar, so you might as well code for that situation.